# goodness of fit of umap

Tags: goodness-of-fit, dimension-reduction

I'm given a 20*122-dim matrix, each column is a 20-element vector. Now I apply umap to the matrix and get a 2*122 matrix and a umap plot. How to measure the goodness of fit of this umap model? Is there any standard way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

UMAP has multiple purposes like clustering, supervised learning and outlier detection.

What exactly do you want to do with UMAP?

In case of clustering, you can take a look at [sklearn cluster evaluation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation) and compare the scores with other algorithms like t-SNE.

To look for the structure, you can reduce your data to 2-3 dimensions and use a scatter plot to eye check the results.

When you have labeled data, you can try to classify them with (nonlinear) classifiers like a random forest and compare the result score (e.g. accuracy) with other dimension reduction techniques like PCA.

Maybe you look for the [trustworthiness](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.trustworthiness.html) from sklearn. You can compare the scores of PCA with the score of UMAP or any other dimension reduction algorithm. [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/on-the-validating-umap-embeddings-2c8907588175)

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I'm using umap to discover the structure of a 20-dim dataset. Cluster doesn't matter.

Comment: I got scatter plots for both umap and pca. But how to compare them? I don't have labels, I try to use both ways as unsupervised. I tried one method named shepard diagram, but it mainly focuses on MDS. I'm not sure it this also works for umap and pca.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I compared UMAP and PCA and found that PCA performs better than UMAP. Is this expected? As I think UMAP is more advance than PCA.

Comment: It depends on the data. UMAP is much more advanced, like you said. You can play around with the hyperparameter of UMAP to improve the results.